# Manual sort objects with anonymous type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
var categories = catList.Select(c => new
{
      Title = c.Web.Title,
      Byline = c[Constants.FieldNames.Byline],
      Url = c[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileRef]
});
```

I will always have maximum three items but could be less.
The Title will always be either (simplified) america, europe or africa

What I need to do is to sort them but not alphabetically before I add databind them to a repeater

The order I need to display them in is

```
europe
africa
america
```

How can I achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order the items by the title's position that you store in a dictionary:

```
var position = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "Europe", 0 },
    { "Africa", 1 },
    { "America", 2 },
};

var categories = catList.Select(c => new ...);
                        .OrderBy(x => position[x.Title]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, by assigning a corresponding order number to each title:

```
var catOrder = new Dictionary<string,int>
{
    { "europe", 1 },
    { "africa", 2 },
    { "america", 3 }
};

var catList = new[] { "america", "europe", "africa" };

var categories =
    catList.Select(c => new { Title = c })
    .OrderBy(c => catOrder[c.Title]);

// result: europe, africa, america
```

If the comparison is more complex, create a class that implements [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) that contains your ordering logic, and pass it to `OrderBy()`.